# css buttons and states

Tags: css

Can you apply `:hover` and `:active` attributes to `input[type=button]`, or do you have to use a class?

Answer (score 1):

You can...* with exceptions. IE6 ONLY supports :hover on a attributes. If you are supporting IE6, you will need to change the class with JS, if not, you can just use :hover (there are also some IE6 hacks available to bypass this)

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers allow you to use `:hover` with any element, but IE is a bit more fiddly about it.

You can use [this hack](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html), or do it with Javascript and event handlers (preferable, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style type="text/css">
        input[type=button]:hover {
            background: red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <input type="button" value="Hit me" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course, beware of IE, but that's a whole different branch of web design. :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a google link.  http://cssbutton.com/forms/ with some examples.  You will find that older IE versions are picky with this sort of thing.